# macOS Mojave iostream not found when compiling

Tags: macos, macports

I am having trouble compiling my program. I am running Mojave 10.14.6. I am using a simple text editor and the terminal to compile and run. I can't compile programs that i know previously worked. Any help would be appreciated.

upon some googling i found some possible solution. I have:

- tried installing "Xcode command line tools"
- tried installing macports and updating
- i have tried running some program in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg(i cant find packages folder in directory)
- cleared some cache(idk what this was. thanks google)

edit: I am trying to write a program in C. I need to bring in iostream for input and output. when i go to compile, it gives

```
   fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
   #include <iostream>
             ^~~~~~~~~
```

Reading online i found it has something to do with apple moving/removing the include folder. None of the solutions posted online seem to be working. I am using the build in compiler (Clang?)

Comment: List, **in detail** what you mean by "having trouble." Give us a list with error message and exactly what you did to get those errors. Just edit your question and add them in. As it stands there really isn't enough info...

Comment: Why would you be installing MacPorts in 2019?

Comment: iostream is C++, not C. Make sure your compiler is expecting C++, not straight C.